# How can I find tutorials for building an application that gets updates from an online website?

Tags: facebook, networking, twitter

I want to build an application that gets updates from online websites like Twitter or Facebook. Currently, I haven't even got a clue on how to do this.

Also, in certain applications, like Doodle Jump, I have seen updates that pop up. Some other applications have a news section that gets updated often. How is it done? Any tutorial or working code will be very helpful.

Comment: This is so vague that you have no real chance of having it answered adequately.  Please clarify, fix grammer and try to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [good tutorial](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/how-to-consume-an-xml-feed-in-aspnet-rss/) I used to do this with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you are interested in building an iPhone app. I don't know if you have any experience working with objective-c or the iPhone SDK, but here is a nice tutorial that touches on some of the concepts you will need.

http://icodeblog.com/2009/07/09/integrating-twitter-into-your-applications/

Comment: Hahah Yeh I've got twitter integrated into my application. I wish I new the term of what this is called. Sorry I don't but Like in doodle jump the game it has a News feed Im guessing its a rss feed that pops up when the is NEWS on some new app or whatever I am wanting that!  Im am trying very hard at learning this Thanks a Million for all of YOUR HELP !!